# What is the wrong with my JSON code?

Tags: javascript, json, jslint

Can anyone tell me why is my JSON file throwing errors when parsing? I am trying to produce a map using kartograph? I get these errors using JSLINT (given below)

```
{
  "proj": { "id": "sinusoidal", 
   "lon0": 134.25},
  "layers": [
    {
      "background": {"special": "sea"},
      "styles": {"fill": "lightblue"}
    },
    {
      "graticule": {"special": "graticule",
      "latitudes": 1,
      "longitudes": 1}
    },
     { "id": "Aus"
       "src": "myfile"
       "simplify": false
       }, 
    { "id": "trees",
      "src": "myfile",
      "simplify": true },
   {'id': 'crops'
      "src": "myfile",
      "simplify": true
   },
     { "id": "depth"
       "src": "myfile",
       "simplify": true
   },
   { "id": "states",
      "src": "myfile"}
  ],

  "export": {
    "width": "auto",
    "height": "auto"
  },
  "bounds": {
    "padding": 0.02,
    "mode": "bbox",
    "data": [92, -44, 181, -2],
    "crop": [112, -44, 154, -9]

  }
}
```

The errors I gt using JSLINT are

```
Line 14, column 8: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 13 and instead saw 'src'.
           "src": "myfile"

Line 14, column 13: Expected ']' to match '[' from line 3 and instead saw ':'.
           "src": "myfile"

Line 14, column 15: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1 and instead saw 'D:/karto/Aus/Ausfull/Ausfull.shp'.
           "src": "myfile"

Line 15, column 8: Expected '(end)' and instead saw 'simplify'.
           "simplify": false
```

* do'nt understand how to solve these errors??

Comment: You're missing lots of commas.

Comment: You're missing `,` in that area.

Comment: `{"id": "Aus" "src": "myfile" "simplify": false}` is missing a few `,`s.

Comment: Don't mix `'` and `"`. Use `"id"` and NOT `'id'`.

Comment: you could catch these errors more easily if you used a standard indentation. I strongly prefer putting braces on their own lines so it's easy to see.

Tools like sublime make this easy: you can highlight multiline regions and tab to indent all the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings must be with double quotes and you missed some commas

```
  {
        "proj": {
            "id": "sinusoidal",
                "lon0": 134.25
        },
            "layers": [{
            "background": {
                "special": "sea"
            },
                "styles": {
                "fill": "lightblue"
            }
        }, {
            "graticule": {
                "special": "graticule",
                    "latitudes": 1,
                    "longitudes": 1
            }
        }, {
            "id": "Aus",
                "src": "myfile",
                "simplify": false
        }, {
            "id": "trees",
                "src": "myfile",
                "simplify": true
        }, {
            "id": "crops",
                "src": "myfile",
                "simplify": true
        }, {
            "id": "depth",
                "src": "myfile",
                "simplify": true
        }, {
            "id": "states",
                "src": "myfile"
        }],

            "export": {
            "width": "auto",
                "height": "auto"
        },
            "bounds": {
            "padding": 0.02,
                "mode": "bbox",
                "data": [92, -44, 181, -2],
                "crop": [112, -44, 154, -9]

        }
    }
```